# Central manager method is not being called ..

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth

i am new to iOS any one please give some suggestion to me.My process to get status about the bluetooth ring scanner. The bluetooth scanner is working fine and my app getting data form the scanner. But now my task is, whenever i open my app ring scanner should connect automatically. and also i want to display the bluetooth status icon in my app.

1) Ring scanner connected already or connected when my app launch - Bluetooth icon (Blue Colour)
2) Ring Scanner not connected - Bluetooth icon (Red colour)
3) Ring Scanner lost connection or sleep due to lack of activity - Bluetooth icon (Grey colour).

i have started working on this concept but centralManager method is not getting called. Here is my code. any one please help me

```
 h.file 

 #import <CoreBluetooth/CoreBluetooth.h>
 @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString   *connected;
 @property (nonatomic) CBCentralManager *bluetoothManager;

 m.file

 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];  
  _bluetoothManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self
                                                         queue:nil
                                                       options:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]
                                                                                           forKey:CBCentralManagerOptionShowPowerAlertKey]];
}

 - (void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central
 {

    NSString *stateString = nil;
    switch(_bluetoothManager.state)
    {
    case CBCentralManagerStateResetting: stateString = @"The connection with the system service was momentarily lost, update imminent."; break;
    case CBCentralManagerStateUnsupported: stateString = @"The platform doesn't support Bluetooth Low Energy."; break;
    case CBCentralManagerStateUnauthorized: stateString = @"The app is not authorized to use Bluetooth Low Energy."; break;
    case CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOff: stateString = @"Bluetooth is currently powered off.";
    {
        UIAlertView *BluetoothOff = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Warning!!" message:@"Turn ON Bluetooth in setting!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [BluetoothOff show];
    } 
    break;
    case CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn: stateString = @"Bluetooth is currently powered on and available to use.";
    {
  // [self.bluetoothManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:nil];
     [self startScan];
    }
    break;
    default: stateString = @"State unknown, update imminent."; 
    break;
    }
    NSLog(@"Bluetooth State: %@",stateString);
    }

    - (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central   didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral*)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI 
   {
    NSLog(@"DiscoverPeripheral@");
   }

    -(void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didRetrievePeripherals:(NSArray *)peripherals
   {
    NSLog(@"RetrievePeripherals@");  
   }

   -(void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didRetrieveConnectedPeripherals:(NSArray *)peripherals
   {
      NSLog(@"RetrieveConnectedPeripherals@");  
   }

   -(void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didFailToConnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral error:(NSError *)error
   {
     NSLog(@"Connection Failed@");  
   }

  -(void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDisconnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral error:(NSError *)error
  {
 NSLog(@"Disconnected@"); 
  }

 - (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didConnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral
  {
   [peripheral setDelegate:self];
   [peripheral discoverServices:nil];
   self.connected = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Connected: %@", peripheral.state == CBPeripheralStateConnected ? @"YES" : @"NO"];
  }

- (void) startScan
  {
    NSLog(@"Start scanning");
    NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber      numberWithBool:YES], CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey, nil];

    [self.bluetoothManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:options];

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You just save the `UUID` of the peripheral in your internal database and try to reconnect it after the application launched using the same `UUID`.

Save it in

```
- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI{
  NSLog(@"peripheral.identifier=%@",peripheral.identifier.UUIDString);
}
```

After connecting with the peripheral you can read any value provided by the scanner.

Comment: Hi Atanu Mondal first thanks for you.. ya that is fine, now my issues is central manager method are not calling.. Once this issue is fixed then i can move forward. Help me to fix this

Comment: Can you try this code

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];  
   _bluetoothManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self  queue:nil];
    _bluetoothManager.delegate=self;

    [_bluetoothManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:nil];
}

Comment: Ya i have tried the code given by you. But still issue is there, methods are not getting called